# MySqlCommand c# - How to ignore custom row parameter whilst replacing other params in command text

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlcommand

So I'm trying to use the following syntax to produce a row number for each result, where:

- `@row` is created as the query runs and
- `@search` is a parameter I've added myself:

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"SET @row = 0;
                    SELECT
                        (@row:= @row + 1) AS row,
                            *
                    FROM
                        clients
                    WHERE
                        name CONCAT('%', @search, '%')";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "whatever");

try
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // blah blah
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cmd.Connection.Close();

}
```

This query works fine if I run the MySQL straight in the database, but I get an error from the c#:

```
Parameter @row must be defined
```

..if I use a `MySqlCommand` object.

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It seems as though MySqlCommand may be attempting to parse and bind `@row` (as it is doing for `@search`)..

Comment: @user2864740 yes that's correct - but how do I tell the object to IGNORE that variable?

Comment: I found "Note. *Prior versions of the provider used the '@' symbol to mark parameters in SQL. This is incompatible with MySQL user variables, so the provider now uses the '?' symbol to locate parameters in SQL.* To support older code, you can set 'old syntax=yes' on your connection string. If you do this, please be aware that an exception will not be throw if you fail to define a parameter that you intended to use in your SQL." (link dead) - so, if such snipped is honest, I would expect code to use `?var` instead of `@var` *for a 'modern' provider* without 'old syntax' enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately.. not so honest: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm (perhaps there is a bug report?)

Comment: Ahh, see the connection string [AllowUserVariables] options: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/ .. that's not confusing at all.